# Total Distance using Foldl

Tags: haskell, tuples, fold

I want get the total distance of a given list, that contains tuples of Floats. I have to guarantee that a list with less than 2 elements is going to output 0.0

What i did so far was this:

```
distancia :: [(Float,Float)] -> Float
distancia [] = 0.0
distancia [(_,_)] = 0.0
distancia (x:y:xs) = foldl(\(xa,ya)(xb,yb) -> sqrt(((xa-xb)**2)+((ya-yb)**2))) 0 xs
```

so the outputs i´m expecting is

```
ghci> distancia [(0,0), (0,0), (1,0), (1,10)]
11.0
ghci> distancia [(1,1), (3,4)]
3.6055512
```

but im getting the following error:

```
t3_fc42035.hs:9:22: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Float'
                  with actual type `(Float, Float)'
    * In the expression:
        foldl
          (\ (xa, ya) (xb, yb) -> sqrt (((xa - xb) ** 2) + ((ya - yb) ** 2)))
          0
          xs
      In an equation for `distancia':
          distancia (x : y : xs)
            = foldl
                (\ (xa, ya) (xb, yb) -> sqrt (((xa - xb) ** 2) + ((ya - yb) ** 2)))
                0
                xs
  |
9 | distancia (x:y:xs) = foldl(\(xa,ya)(xb,yb) -> sqrt(((xa-xb)**2)+((ya- yb)**2))) 0 xs
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

t3_fc42035.hs:9:47: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `(Float, Float)'
                  with actual type `Float'
    * In the expression: sqrt (((xa - xb) ** 2) + ((ya - yb) ** 2))
      In the first argument of `foldl', namely
        `(\ (xa, ya) (xb, yb)
            -> sqrt (((xa - xb) ** 2) + ((ya - yb) ** 2)))'
      In the expression:
        foldl
          (\ (xa, ya) (xb, yb) -> sqrt (((xa - xb) ** 2) + ((ya - yb) ** 2)))
      0
      xs
  |
9 | distancia (x:y:xs) = foldl(\(xa,ya)(xb,yb) -> sqrt(((xa-xb)**2)+((ya-yb)**2))) 0 xs
  |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't understand why i have to match the type (Float,Float)

Comment: The first parameter in the "fold-function" is the accumulator, not a 2-tuple, so the distance "thus far".

Comment: I thought i could use other things besides the acc. So i need to do another function that gives me the tuples right?

Comment: not *per se*, but I'm not convinced that a `foldl` will produce the most elegant code, no :)

Comment: Hint: `(zip <*> tail) [p1, p2, p3, p4, ...]` will give you a list `[(p1, p2), (p2, p3), (p3, p4), ...]`. Also, `(zip <*> tail) [x] == []`, so the only special case is an empty input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Folding, even if it feels like a reasonable approach, is not the right tool for this particuluar case since to calculate an accumulator value you need two items from the list at once along with the accumulator itself. This is not possible so no folding.

Could be done like;

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let dist = sum . (zipWith hypot <*> tail)
Prelude|            where hypot = \(a,b) (c,d) -> sqrt((a-c)^2 + (b-d)^2)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> dist [(0,0), (0,0), (1,0), (1,10)]
11.0
Prelude> dist [(1,1), (3,4)]
3.605551275463989
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. i have to use for my homework either foldl or map, so i guess i'll use map. thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 0):

So i was trying to come up with a way to use foldl, because on this function i really have to use a foldl or foldr. But i can't get all the examples working

```
distancia :: [(Float,Float)] -> Float
distancia [] = 0.0
distancia [(_,_)] = 0.0
distancia (x:y:xs) = foldl(\acc -> acc + (hypo x y)) 0 (y:xs)
 where
  hypo (xa,ya)(xb,yb) =  sqrt (((xa-xb)**2)+((ya-yb)**2))
```

I'm getting a wrong input when a list begins with [(0,0),(0,0)], it always gives me a wrong input, but if the list begins with [(0,0),(1,0),(0,0)] it works.

```
*Main> distancia [(0,0), (0,0), (1,0), (1,10)]
0,0
```

but if i do this

```
*Main> distancia [(0,0), (1,0), (0,0), (1,10)]
3,0
```

but when use this examples it works

```
*Main> distancia [(0,0), (1,1), (0,0), (-1, -1), (0,0)]
5.656854

*Main> distancia [(1,1), (0,0)]
1.4142135
```

What is wrong?

Comment: If you insist on using folding you need an accumulator in the type of `(Float, (Float,Float))` wheras the first is the distance and the second is the starting coordinate. I leave it up to you to discover the iterating function. Then there is another problem as whether the origin would be the starting point... ie `(0,(0,0))`  or what? It might be a time to consider `head`s and `tail`s :)